# Unable to capture alpha numeric data using regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am using regular expression extractor in JMeter to extract the response data which contains something like the following:

**Set-Cookie: X-Tr-Auth=b1eada98-ffa1-45a3-522e-591a84dd48f2; Path=/msf; Expires=Fri, 05 Dec 2064 09:25:44 UTC; HttpOnly**

The above data is sent from the server after user logs in, I need to use the above authcode to post a JSON body.

I have set the regular expression extractor to the following values:

```
Reference Name: authcode

Regular Expression: Set-Cookie: "(.+?)"

Template: $1$

Match No. : 1

Default Value: 0
```

I am getting 0 every time I run the test. I saw a similar question in Stack-overflow with no satisfactory answer. Need expert advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the cookie value without having to extract it using regex.

1. Add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line into *user.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter if it's running (reading properties from file is not dynamic and performen on load)
3. Add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan
4. Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of the request you need to parametrize and configure it as follows:

   - Name: `Cookie X-Tr-Auth`
   - Value: `${authcode}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression,

```
Auth\=(.*); Path
```

with remaining settings which you have used.

In this I am expecting you need only authcode value, As Authocde label is constant no need to extract it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
But now I am trying to use it to POST a JSON request with header value set to Cookie X-Tr-Auth=${authcode}. But the request does not show the value.

Comment: Please upvote or accept answer if it was helpful. Check for scoping issues. If value is getting extracted successfully  then it should be available with ${authocode}.

Comment: I have set the following in HTTP Header Manager 

Content-Type application/json

Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie: X-Tr-Auth=${authcode}

But the request does not show any Cookie field all the other fields are shown. Am i making some mistake?