# unable to pass customn header value using Header Manager in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have Test plan where the User Logins and recieves an authcode which I am capturing in a variable **authcode** the following requests have to be made using the authcode as an header value eg: **Cookie X-Tr-Auth=${authcode}**

I have set the following in HTTP Header Manager

**Content-Type: application/json**

**Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch**

**Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8**

**Cookie:   X-Tr-Auth=${authcode}**

But the request does not show any Cookie field, all the other fields are shown. Am i missing something?

Please see the request Body:

POST http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/xxx

POST data:
\"xxxxx\":{\"xx\":\"xx\",\"x\":\"xxxxxx\",\"x\":{\"Tickers\":[\"xxxx.x\",\"xxxx.x\",\"xxx.N\",\"xxx.N\",\"xxx.N\",\"xxxx.xx\"]}}}

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length: 134
Host: 10.248.70.205:8080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

This request is failing with 401 Unathorised error. Experts please help!

Comment: Try the steps mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313024/unable-to-capture-alpha-numeric-data-using-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmete

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar), not HTTP Header Manager to set/override cookies.

Comment: I tried the HTTP cookie manager but it dint worked. I have the following configuration in cookie manager

Name: authcode
Value: Cookie X-Tr-Auth=${authcode}; HttpOnly
Domain: http://10.248.70.204:8080
Path: /msf/auth/login

Comment: I believe that `Name` should be `X-Tr-Auth` and `Value` = `${authcode}`